# How to use Device Emulator to debug my WinCE application

Tags: visual-studio-2005, windows-ce, device-emulation

I am working with an MFC application built on a WinCE platform in Visual Studio. I need to debug this application and I cannot do it using KITL and the hardware. I tried to use Device Emulator for this:
I started a new Platform Builder Project (PDA Device, enterprise webpad). I built it after ensureing that KITL was enabled and so was kernel debugger. Once built, i set the target connectivity options as ce device, download and transport set to Device Emulator and Debugger is KdStub.
Once I hit Attach to Device, the doload to target window pops up and then the RelDir window also does. However nothing happens after this and in the output window it says:
PB Debugger The Kernel Debugger is waiting to connect with target.
Please guide me on what I need to do to debug my application.
Thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

Why are you enabling KITL and kernel debugger?  They are used for debugging the OS and drivers. Turn them off for application development because you'll be using corecon.